# Recolor imagesc Inf values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, infinity

I am using `imagesc` to display data from matrices. The matrices contain `NaNs` and `Inf` values. I am able to recolour `NaNs` to the background colour. I am using the jet colour map and I would like to recolour `Inf` values to black or another colour that is not the background colour or on the jet colour scheme. Matlab by default colours `Inf` values as same as the maximum value. What follows is a brief example code, to give an idea of what I mean.

```
 a = [1 2 NaN; 4 Inf 6; 7 5 3];
%// Matrix of data
    test_image= imagesc(a);
%// Creates imagesc figure.
    colormap('jet');
%// Uses jet color scheme.
    set(test_image,'alphadata',~isnan(a))
%// Ignores NaN values and sets NaN values to background colour.
    colorbar
%// Adds a colorbar
```

So in this example what I would want is middle cell (2,2) to be black. Not the same colour as the maximum value of 7 in the bottom left hand corner (3,1).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to define your own colormap:

```
cm = [jet(255) ; 0 0 0];
colormap(cm);

imagesc(a);
caxis([min(a(:)) max(a(:))+1]);
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on a specific Matlab forum run by Matlab central. People don't always answer that forum. The answer I got did not quite work but put me on the right track. I came up with the following:

```
a = [1 2 NaN; 4 Inf 6; 7 5 3];
% sample data
infRGB = reshape([0 0 0],1,1,3);   
%set to RGB triple for desired color for inf values in this case black
%denoted by [0 0 0].
infimgdata = repmat(infRGB, size(a,1), size(a,2)); 
%same size as "a" but all the one color
infimg = image(infimgdata, 'alphadata', ~isnan(a));  
%plots an image based on 'infimgdata' excludes NaN's therefore making NaN
%values white
hold on
%plot to same figure
test_image = imagesc(a,'alphadata', ~(isnan(a)|isinf(a)));
%plot data
colormap(jet());
colorbar
hold off
% stop plotting to the same figure
```